# How to read a Set with PofSerializer

Tags: java, serialization, collections, deserialization

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize a bunch of Collections and I'm having trouble reading the `Set<E>`.
I've created a new class: CollectionTypesSerializer to serialize/deserialize all my collections but it's not working.
Here's a sample of my code:

```
public class CollectionTypesPofSerializer implements PofSerializer {

private static final int ID = 0;
        // Set
        private static final int SET1NUMBER = 1;                            //Set<Number>
        private static final int SET2MAPBASICTYPESCOLLECTION = 2;           //Set<Map<BasicTypesCollection>>
        private static final int SET3INNERTYPESPRIMITIVEINNERTYPES = 3;     //Set<InnerTypes.PrimitiveInnerTypes>

@Override
public Object deserialize(PofReader reader) throws IOException {

    CollectionTypes collection = new CollectionTypes();

    collection.id = reader.readInt(ID);

    collection.set1 = (Set<Number>) reader.readCollection(SET1NUMBER, null);
    collection.set2 = (Set<Map<BasicTypes, Collection<?>>>) reader.readCollection(SET2MAPBASICTYPESCOLLECTION, null);
    collection.set3 = (Set<InnerTypes.PrimitiveInnerTypes>) reader.readCollection(SET3INNERTYPESPRIMITIVEINNERTYPES, null);

    reader.readRemainder();
return collection;
}
```

I have a lot of other Collections in this method and they don't have the same problem.
I know what the problem is, I can't use `reader.readCollection(...)` with Set and the cast is not enough. However, I don't know any other way to do it. Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem:

```
collection.set1 = new HashSet<Number>(reader.readCollection(SET1NUMBER, null));
collection.set2 = new HashSet<Map<BasicTypes, Collection<?>>>(reader.readCollection(SET2MAPBASICTYPESCOLLECTION, null));
collection.set3 = new HashSet<InnerTypes.PrimitiveInnerTypes>(reader.readCollection(SET3INNERTYPESPRIMITIVEINNERTYPES, null));
```

It was a cast problem. Can't be done that way. This one works :)